# Detox on Android - can't run tests in parallel

Tags: react-native, detox

I'm trying to speed up my detox e2e tests on Android so I thought I'll try to run them on multiple devices. I was able to easily do the same on iOS using the **--workers** flag but that doesn't seem to work at all on Android.

Here is my relevant detox config piece:

```
"android.sim.debug": {
    "binaryPath": "...",
    "build": "...",
    "type": "android.attached",
    "name": ".*"
  },
```

Then I'm using this command to run the tests:

```
detox test --configuration android.sim.debug --workers 2
```

What I tried to do:

- I fired up 2 emulators
- I run detox tests with the command above
- But the tests are only running on one of the emulators, the other one is being ignored

Any suggestions how can I run these tests on multiple emulators?

Comment: I've also struggled to get parallel tests working on android. The thing that confuses me is the cli help states that --workers is for "iOS Only".  Check for yourself: `./node_modules/.bin/detox test --help`. But this is not mentioned in the docs. So it's all rather confusing. I've created a GitHub issue asking for clarification: https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/2729

Comment: @badsyntax ah I totally missed that... I've seen a video from Detox that showed tests running on multiple simlators - so I think it's definitely possible somehow!